# recursion: closure vs. without closure - which one is better?

Tags: javascript, performance, recursion, closures

Let's say I'm using recursion to multiply an array by a number, which version is better in terms of performance?

Version 1: - No Closure

```js
var recursiveMultiplier = function(arr, num) {
  if (!arr.length) {
    return arr;
  }

  var lastElement = arr.pop();
  recursiveMultiplier(arr, num);
  arr.push(lastElement * num);
  return arr;
}

var x = [1, 2, 3],
  num = 2;
var y = recursiveMultiplier(x, num);
console.log(y);
```

Version 2: - With Closure

```js
var recursiveMultiplier = function(arr, num) {
  var newArray = [];
  var mult = function(a) {
    if (a.length) {
      newArray[a.length - 1] = a.pop() * num;
      mult(a);
      return newArray;
    }
    return;
  }
  return mult(arr);
}

var x = [1, 2, 3],
  num = 2;
var y = recursiveMultiplier(x, num);
console.log(y);
```

Comment: If you're concerned about performance, don't use recursion.

Comment: The two functions aren't equivalent. In the first, you remove all the elements from the array, then restore them. In the second, you transfer the elements to a new array and multiply them on the way, emptying the contents of the original.

Comment: Your first concern should be that those two function do very different things with their arguments.

Comment: I'm just studying for interviews...and trying to think of all possible ways this question can be asked.

Comment: @RobG they are not equivalent indeed. just different ways to come up with the same solution.

Comment: If you just want to see which is faster, go to [*https://jsperf.com/*](https://jsperf.com/). But test in a number of browsers and various test cases as results will likely not be consistent across implementations.

Comment: @RobG just an interview prep both have the same time complexity, but one includes a closure...that's why i wanted to know if it affects the solution

Comment: If it's just about simplicity, hard to go past `arr.forEach((x,i,a) => a[i] = x*num)`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG ooh nice one! Thanks!

Comment: Of course `(x,i,a)` is more maintainable as `(value, index, array)` but comments don't leave a lot of room. ;-)